# Prevent R .rmd html document from skipping when using datatables in tabsets

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, r-markdown, dt

I'm knitting an HTML file from .rmd with tables produced with the R `DT` package in tabsets. There's a bunch of info before the tabs start, so the user has to scroll down to them, which is fine. The problem is that when scrolling far enough to show the whole table in the first tab, clicking on the next tab causes the page to skip back up to the header of the table, so the user has to scroll back down to show the table, which is annoying with several tabs and long tables.

Here's my .rmd thus far:

````
---
title: "Tab Testing"
output: html_document
---

# Some random text {.tabset}

```{r, echo=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
# libraries
library(DT)
# bunch of random text
textFun <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}

rText <- textFun(500)
```
Scroll down and see how the page skips when selecting Tab 2.

`r rText`

## Tab 1

```{r}
datatable(mtcars)
```
## Tab 2

```{r}
datatable(iris)
```
````

Once I click through all of the tabs, the page will stick when switching tabs, so I suspect I need some JavaScript or JQuery to get the tables to load up before the tabs are clicked to get the page to stick in the first place. I tried adding this chunk after the first r code chunk but it didn't do anything:

````
```{js}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.display').DataTable();
} );
```
````

I poked around over at https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/ but didn't see anything that would help me (or recognize it as such). Any pointers in the right direction would be excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test to add something after each tab ? Maybe it will reduce the skip effect.

Like :

````
## Tab 1

```{r}
datatable(mtcars)
```

<div style="height:500px;display:block;"> </div>

## Tab 2

```{r}
datatable(iris)
```

<div style="height:500px;display:block;"> </div>
````

Comment: That sort of works. One has to guess at the correct height for each table and it seems like there needs to be a big gap below the div for the skip to really get reduced, which gets messy with lower-level nested tabs. I'd like something more programmatic that doesn't require a large gap below the div.